# Trying to improve algorithm to be more generic

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, containers, sequential

I came up with the following algo to remove consecutive duplicates in a vector, but I am looking for a way to improve it and to be able to use it with other sequential containers.

I've looked around for a common parent container type, but I can't figure anything out so far.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
template <class T>
void erase_adjacent_duplicate (std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin();

    while (it != v.end()) 
    {
        if(std::adjacent_find(it, v.end()) == v.end())
        {
            it = v.end();
        }
        else
        {
            it = std::adjacent_find(it, v.end()) - 1;
            v.erase(it + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the problem currently faced with your code is what exactlly?

Comment: Well, typically you would do it by passing two iterators. Also, are you assuming the container is already sorted?

Comment: @user0042 I'm trying to find a way to edit it so I could pass a list or a vector or a forward_list...etc...

Comment: @NirFriedman it is already sorted yes, in my case I use it on a forward_list, but as mentioned, I'm trying to find a more "generic" way

Comment: Could be `v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already general algorithm `std::unique` in the C++ standard library that (The C++ Standard )

> eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of
>   equivalent elements referred to by the iterator i in the range [first
>   + 1,last) for which the following conditions hold: *(i - 1) == *i or pred(*(i - 1), *i) != false.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 };

    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 3 2
```

Take into account that arrays do not have member functions like `erase`. So you can not write a general function for each sequential container that includes a call of `erase`.

Comment: But with std::unique I couldn't hold a list like {1,2,3,2,3,1,2} right? Wouldn't it return something like {1,2,3}? My goal is really only to delete consecutive elements, not to have them apprearing only once.

Comment: @VincentDM: Look at documentation. `std::unique` only "removes" adjacent equal elements.

Comment: @VincentDM The algorithm deals with consecutive groups of equivalent elements. See the demonstrative program in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for a common parent container, use iterators as input. Then you can write your algorithm such that it's valid for example for all InputIterators. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator.

Comment: But how to erase element from container then ?

Comment: Up to you. std::remove() works without knowing the container type. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: You have to call `container.erase` afterward. Iterators are useful, but most of the time the working range is the full container, so it makes sense to have interfaces which allow container as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You may template for a container type, something like:

```
template <class Cont>
void erase_adjacent_duplicate(Cont& cont)
{
     cont.erase(std::unique(std::begin(cont), std::end(cont)), std::end(cont));
}
```

Comment: Why not pass the two iterators into the function? Then you could use it with C arrays. This is the idiomatic way.

Comment: @NirFriedman: You cannot erase elements from c-array. (size is fixed).